# Convert column in df to float (sounds simple)

Tags: python, floating-point

Am fairly new to code but have managed to solve most problems, here though I am stuck. I have a column in a df where all the values are a string in brackets for example '[0.0987]', I can't seem to convert these to float in order to calculate the mean. Every method results in an error such as: 'could not convert string to float:' or 'Could not convert to numeric'. Can't share a link so image below shows an example csv I am loading into pandas.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip the brackets from the values.

```
df["qout"].str.strip('[]').astype(float)
```

Strip - will remove the [] from the column

astype - Will typecast the data as float

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to strip the brackets. Does this work? `qout_as_float = float(qout[1:-1])`